# Character Encoding from Mssql to PHP,Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

My mssql is in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS character encoding. Now I am creating a site in PHP and Mysql. However I am unable to get correct the encoding in PHP. My browser shows garbled characters. I have tried the following command to encode the string without any success:

```
iconv("CP1252","UTF-8",'àú îèøåúéðå. ');
```

Target language is Hebrew.

Comment: How does MS SQL relate to the thing? There are also so many pages and questions on how to use UTF8 with PHP and MySQL that it should be quite easy to get it right. Not to mention you haven't shown any relevant code to help anyone pinpoint the issue.

Comment: My previous database is in MSSQl SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS encoding. Well I managed to convert the data into Mysql but unable to get the right character encoding while showing the data into Browser.

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, PHP... What DBMS do you use now and getting problem with? Please, add PHP tag if you are having problem with encoding on the page. What is the encoding of your php files?